# Custom static site generator in github

Tags: github-pages

I am a big fan of `jekyll` and know that it can be used to host static sites on github. The question is that from what i know of github provides hosting for static sites, but at the same time it builds and compiles jekyll into static app which is in ruby.

Is there a possibility of writing a custom static site generator in some other language like `python` or is `jekyll` the only supported framework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative (avoiding the static app part) is [**Hugo**](https://github.com/spf13/hugo), build in Go ([golang.org](https://golang.org/)).

That way, you only work with a local static generator and upload the result to your GitHub Pages.

> What I meant what as in jekyll where the app is uploaded and not the static content is there any alternative of that kind or is it possible ?

[DirtyF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2604321/dirtyf) comments and offers an alternative:

> Jekyll is the only supported static site generator on GitHub, you can use other generators but have to push the compiled files on your repo.
>   [pages.gitlab.io](http://pages.gitlab.io/) offers support for more static site generators and you can mirror a repository to GitHub.

Comment: i am guessing that in Hugo we only upload the static content generated ? What i meant what as in jekyll where the app is uploaded and not the static content is there any alternative of that kind or is it possible ?

Comment: @georoot not to my knowledge. Working with the static content alone seems easier.

Comment: Jekyll is the only supported static site generator on GitHub, you can use other generators but have to push the compiled files on your repo.

https://pages.gitlab.io/ offers support for more static site generators and you can mirror a repository to GitHub.

Comment: @DirtyF Thank you for mentioning an alternative. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.